# Take free space on multiple machines and make one virtual hard drive (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ubuntu-10.04

We have a number of `Ubuntu 10.04` machines connected in the LAN. Each of the machines has a lot of free space.

I wish to utilize this free space such that it would create a virtual (I do not mean VHD here) hard disk or a virtual folder wherein everyone can store and share stuff.

Is something like this possible? or something close to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this - you could start by looking at [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/)

*"GlusterFS is a clustered file-system capable of scaling to several peta-bytes. It aggregates various storage bricks over Infiniband RDMA or TCP/IP interconnect into one large parallel network file system. Storage bricks can be made of any commodity hardware such as x86-64 server with SATA-II RAID and Infiniband or GigE interconnect. "*

But be warned that it can be a bit of a pain to manage and performance can be sluggish.

I have heard some good things about [MogileFS](http://www.danga.com/mogilefs/), but have not used it yet.

PS: A colleague has just mentioned [Tahoe](http://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs)

Comment: Great suggestions! I'll try them out and get back again. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Nikhil Patil Any luck?

Comment: Frankly, I just studies the three but couldn't give all of them a full try. Have a tight schedule nowadays cause of the product release we have coming. Can only try them after April EOM!